# package installed through pip3, does not create symlink automatically on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, centos, symlink

### Example

On MacOS10.14.6

```
>>pip3 install qrcode
...
>>qr "abc" > test.png #Create a QRcode
command not found: qr
>>command -v qr ; echo $?
1
```

On CentOS7

```
>>pip3 install qrcode
...
>>command -v qr ; echo $?
/usr/local/bin/qr
0
```

qr file in CentOS:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from qrcode.console_scripts import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

If I put 'qr' in the `/usr/local/bin` of MacOS, the command `qr "abc" > test.png` will run successfully on MacOS.

## Q:

Why doesn't it create the 'qr' in MacOS automatically?
How could I make it?

Comment: i'm not sure if you have to symlink yourself, it might be a better idea to add the directory containing `qrcode` to your path

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise of your question. If I install a **Python** module on my Mac using `pip` I wouldn't expect it to change my PATH for anything I might run from `bash`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It will not change the PATH. I just need it to create an executable file 
automatically in my PATH after I installed a python module.

Comment: @MCO `qrcode` does not have an executable file for `bash`. So I still need to create a 'qr' file to my PATH. It will automatically create the "qr" file to PATH in CentOS, but it won't be on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

One best solution of your problem is to use **virtualenv**

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv ENV
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
```

Then in this virtual env install **qrcode**

```
pip3 install Image
pip3 install qrcode
```

And your should be able to use qr command from you terminal given *you are in your virtual environment.*